# When using python3.5.3 getting KeyError 0:0

Tags: python-3.x, keyerror

we are kind of new to coding with python3 and we have been successful using other scripts, but trying to set up this wind vane is not working for us, using a list in python3. Any help is greatly appreciated if anyone can point my 10 year old and I in the right direction. We are getting a KeyError 0:0 after reading line 36 (print directive) Here is our code:

```
 from gpiozero import MCP3008
 import time
 adc = MCP3008(channel=1)
 import math
 wind = 0
 values = []
 volts = {
 0.4: 0.0,
 1.4: 22.5,
 1.2: 45.0,
 2.8: 67.5,
 2.7: 90.0,
 2.9: 112.5,
 2.2: 135.0,
 2.5: 157.5,
 1.8: 180.0,
 2.0: 202.5,
 0.7: 225.0,
 0.8: 247.5,
 2.8: 67.5,
 2.7: 90.0,
 2.9: 112.5,
 2.2: 135.0,
 2.5: 157.5,
 1.8: 180.0,
 2.0: 202.5,
 0.7: 225.0,
 0.8: 247.5,
 0.1: 270.0,
 0.3: 292.5,
 0.2: 315.5,
 0.6: 337.5
 }

 while True:
      wind = round (adc.value * 3.3,1)
      if not wind in volts:
           print('Unknown value ' + str(wind) + ' ' + str(volts[wind]))
      else:
           print('found ' + str(wind) + ' ' + str(volts[wind]))
```

Error we are getting:

```
 File "direction-test.py", line 36, in <module>
     print('Unknown value ' + str(wind) + ' ' + str(volts[wind]))
 KeyError: 0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

`volts[wind]` gets the value of the `wind` key in the `volts` dictionary. For example, if `wind = 0.4`, `volts[wind]` gets the value `0.0` from the `volts` dictionary.

```
if not wind in volts:
    print('Unknown value ' + str(wind) + ' ' + str(volts[wind]))
```

In your code above, you're checking to see `if not wind in volts:` and when it finds that the key is not in the dictionary, you're trying to print the non-existent key's value in line 38.

In short, remove `str(volts[wind])` from line 38 to get rid of the KeyError. You can find a little more about Python dictionaries [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp).

Comment: Ok, do you mean a non-existent voltage value? I did comment out section "+ ' ' + str(volts[wind]))" just to see what happened and it did print the unknown value. I guess we are wondering if there is something wrong with the code or if our voltage value is non-existent causing the error? It seems more like code to us. Thank you so far, we really appreciate it.

Comment: @Joe, I added a bit more to my answer, plus a link that may be helpful for learning about Python dictionaries. Good luck!

Comment: Ok, I did get this working somewhat, but I am trying to upload the darn thing to Weather Underground and having a hard time. I will post more tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: hi @Joe, please flag this answer as correct if this solves your question. thanks